# Can iOS shortcuts enter text at the current cursor position?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I would like to enter some Shortcuts-generated text into an app which is not Shortcuts-aware. The app offers a text entry field so I would like to be able to place the cursor at the right point in it, run the shortcut, and have the text entered.